# Geocoder.getFromLocation() returns addresses in arabic

Tags: android, google-api, google-geocoder

Im using Geocoder on Android devices from Israel. Up until a few weeks ago everything worked fine and when i was doing reverse geocoding all addresses were received in hebrew. But at some point i started getting the same addresses in arabic.

This is a sample code im running (the lat/lon is in Tel-Aviv) :

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(32.087765863162346, 34.781454205513, 1);
```

When i inspect 'addresses' i get the following printout :

> [Address[addressLines=[0:"عمنوئيل هرومي 26",1:"Tel Aviv",2:"Israel"],feature=26,admin=null,sub-admin=null,locality=Tel Aviv,thoroughfare=عمنوئيل هرومي,postalCode=null,countryCode=IL,countryName=Israel,hasLatitude=true,latitude=32.0877767,hasLongitude=true,longitude=34.7813859,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]]

Please note that the devices are not localized to israel. meaning, Locale.getDefault() has "US" and "en" as country and language codes.

I already opened a bug in the Geocoder issue tracker - http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6182 - but was referred to the Android issue tracker. Opened another one over there - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64382 - but it seems like the bug is not even in the android device side but in the Geocoder backend service. So im in a dead end.

I'd appreciate if anybody that knows anybody that knows someone from the responsible team in Google will let them know. Thanks.

**EDIT:** since i sense that questions posted here that are not exactly formed as questions are not very appreciated, let me rephrase - Does anyone know an issue tracker where its possible to open an issue regarding the android Geocoder backend service ? Again, thanks.

Comment: The only solution i can think of is switching to the Geocoding HTTP API which returns addresses in english.... Does it returns only in English? or can use local seting as well? (the HTTP ver)

Comment: You can try. there is a 'language' parameter - [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by setting a Locale in the Geocoder init,
you can do something like this:

```
Locale lHebrew = new Locale("he");
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, lHebrew);
```

Let me know if the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i dont think this can be a solution. Many devices in israel are not localized and hard coding "he" is obviously not a real option if an app is intended to be used globally.